# Javascript data send to python flask with ajax nad message 400 - Bad request

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, flask

Javascript data send to python flask with ajax and message 400 - Bad request

I use ajax and I send a data from js to flask.
I send a name "john" to url "/name" and I want flask request it. Actually I can request it and print "John".
But there return 400 - Bad Request. Hope help!!!

Here is my code:

HTML + JS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HOME ||</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function send(){
                var data={"name":"John"};
                alert(data["name"]);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:"/name",
                    data:JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                });
                document.location.href="/name";
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            send()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Python flask:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import request
import json

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="html")

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/name', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def name():
    print(request.get_json(force=True)["name"])
    return "ok"

app.run()
```

Terminal:

```
PS C:\Python\flask\test2> python app.py
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [06/May/2021 15:31:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
John
127.0.0.1 - - [06/May/2021 15:31:15] "POST /name HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/May/2021 15:31:15] "GET /name HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here `>> **document.location.href="/name";**`
This line of code is calling a get request to /name in Flask.

Inside /name you are trying to obtain `**request.get_json(force=True)["name"]**`, but this isn't in the get request.

One option would be to delete **document.location.href="/name";** so you are not sending a get request

Or you can check if this argument was passed in Flask by writing:

**if 'name' in request.get_json(force=True):
print(request.get_json(force=True)["name"])
return "ok"
else:
return "ok"**

This should hopefully handle the bad request error as we are checking if the key exists before accessing it.

Comment: Thx for your help. I want to send the data ("John") to flask like a html form and show name in "/name". How can I do this work. Hope for help

Comment: Just to clarify you want to send the name "John" to Flask and then return the name on a new html page?

Comment: This youtube video will show you a quick way of understanding Ajax and Flask. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZWtHsM3Y5A

The youtube video also discuses get and post requests.

Comment: Yes, I want to send the name "John" to Flask and return the name on a new html page.